# Python find key in dictionary associated with a number of value

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to search in a dictionary two elements for their value and not for their key.

I have the following code but it does not search for the value of the dict

```
for key in val["timeSlot"]:
    for value in val[key]:
        if test_date in value:
            print "found it!"
```

any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you iterate over the `val[key]`, and furthermore you do an additional membercheck with `test_date in value`.

Comment: maybe give an example dictionary and its desired output.

Comment: If you share a minimal example you get help faster and we spend less time answering the wrong questions -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_key(dictionary,value):
    for k in dictionary.keys():
        if value in dictionary[k]:
            return k
```

use `d.keys()` - it returns a `list` of all the keys in a dictionary. Call the function like this inside the `for key in val["timeslot"]` loop -

```
get_key(val[key],test_date)
```

Answer (score 3):

One trick with dictionaries is that, although each key is unique, the values can repeat. This means that each value may correspond to more than one key. So...

```
    def get_dict_keys(d, val):
        matches = []
        for k in d.keys():
            if d[k] == val:
                matches.append(k)
        return matches
```

And if you like list comprehensions...

```
    def get_dict_keys(d, val):
        return [k for k in d.keys() if d[k] == val]
```